# How to get rid of parts of the message recived from GMail API

Tags: python, regex, gmail-api

I successfully get the message from the GMail API. And the message looks something like this:

```
"""
Blah blah blah blah

CONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE
This e-mail message and all attached files are intended only for the \n person to whom it is addressed and may contain information protected by \n law, and any confidential information. If this e-mail message was sent to \n the wrong person we warn that any unauthorised use of this e-mail \n message and attached files is strictly prohibited. If you are not the \n intended recipient, please destroy all copies of the original message from your computer.
```

Now I want get rid of this "Confidentiality Notice" and everything after that, getting only the message body. What should I use? Regular expressions? The relevant part of my code is:

```
def getMessageBody(self, msg_id):
        try:
            message = self.service.users().messages().get(userId=self.user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
            msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('utf-8'))
            mime_msg = email.message_from_string(msg_str)
            messageMainType = mime_msg.get_content_maintype()
        if messageMainType == 'multipart':
        for part in mime_msg.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
                return part.get_payload()
        return ""
    elif messageMainType == 'text':
        return mime_msg.get_payload()
except errors.HttpError, error:
        print("An error occurred: %s" % error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something crude like

```
return part.get_payload().split('\nCONFIDENTIALITY NOTICE\n')[0]
```

to truncate every body part which contains this string (and conveniently pass through all others without modification).

In the general case, there is no convention for identifying this type of section -- it's just a fragment of the body text with no specific machine-readable markup -- and you can't easily predict what laws or local customs shape its wording (except in very broad terms; organizations and jurisdictions which require this are idiotic). As long as you are dealing with a small set of templates for which you have representative samples, ideally in languages you understand, it's doable in practice, though.